# Correlation Matrix as Input for Lavaan

Tags: r

Is it possible to use a correlation matrix as input for Lavaan? I have searched the web but was not able to find an answer. Many Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid that we have too few information to help you. Could you please tell us more. What is Lavaan? is it a package in R is it in Rbase? What is your issue exactly? I would recommend these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to maximize your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 2):

The [lavaan](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/index.html) package is used to conduct latent variable analysis. While lavaan does support using a [variance / covariance matrix as input to the procedure](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/tutorial.pdf) (see pp. 30 - 31 of the Lavaan tutorial for an example), it does not support use of a correlation matrix as input.